# Ошибка gtk + rust

Tags: rust, gtk

Делал по инструкции на сайте: http://gtk-rs.org
В ходе сборки вышла такая ошибка в консоли:

```
 Updating registry `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`
 Downloading gtk v0.3.0
 Downloading glib v0.4.1
 Downloading gtk-sys v0.5.0
 Downloading glib-sys v0.5.0
 Downloading gobject-sys v0.5.0
 Downloading bitflags v1.0.1
 Downloading gdk v0.7.0
 Downloading pango v0.3.0
 Downloading gio v0.3.0
 Downloading cairo-rs v0.3.0
 Downloading gdk-pixbuf-sys v0.5.0
 Downloading gdk-pixbuf v0.3.0
 Downloading gdk-sys v0.5.0
 Downloading cairo-sys-rs v0.5.0
 Downloading libc v0.2.36
 Downloading gio-sys v0.5.0
 Downloading lazy_static v1.0.0
 Downloading pkg-config v0.3.9
 Downloading atk-sys v0.5.0
 Downloading pango-sys v0.5.0
 Downloading c_vec v1.2.1
 Downloading winapi v0.2.8
   Compiling gio v0.3.0
   Compiling gdk-pixbuf v0.3.0
   Compiling gtk v0.3.0
   Compiling cairo-rs v0.3.0
   Compiling gdk v0.7.0
   Compiling lazy_static v1.0.0
   Compiling libc v0.2.36
   Compiling winapi v0.2.8
   Compiling c_vec v1.2.1
   Compiling bitflags v1.0.1
   Compiling pkg-config v0.3.9
   Compiling cairo-sys-rs v0.5.0
   Compiling gtk-sys v0.5.0
   Compiling gdk-pixbuf-sys v0.5.0
   Compiling gdk-sys v0.5.0
   Compiling glib-sys v0.5.0
   Compiling pango-sys v0.5.0
   Compiling atk-sys v0.5.0
   Compiling gio-sys v0.5.0
   Compiling gobject-sys v0.5.0
   Compiling glib v0.4.1
   Compiling pango v0.3.0
   Compiling ru v0.1.0 (file:///D:/rust/ru)
error: linking with `gcc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "gcc" "-Wl,--enable-long-section-names" "-fno-use-linker-plugin" "-Wl,--nxcompat" "-nostdlib" "-m64" "C:\\Users\\Илья\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\crt2.o" "C:\\Users\\Илья\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rsbegin.o" "-L" "C:\\Users\\Илья\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\ru-73038e7f2f7b39bd.ru0.rcgu.o" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\ru-73038e7f2f7b39bd.ru1.rcgu.o" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\ru-73038e7f2f7b39bd.ru10.rcgu.o" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\ru-73038e7f2f7b39bd.ru11.rcgu.o" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\ru-73038e7f2f7b39bd.ru12.rcgu.o" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\ru-73038e7f2f7b39bd.ru13.rcgu.o" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\ru-73038e7f2f7b39bd.ru14.rcgu.o" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\ru-73038e7f2f7b39bd.ru15.rcgu.o" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\ru-73038e7f2f7b39bd.ru2.rcgu.o" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\ru-73038e7f2f7b39bd.ru3.rcgu.o" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\ru-73038e7f2f7b39bd.ru4.rcgu.o" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\ru-73038e7f2f7b39bd.ru5.rcgu.o" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\ru-73038e7f2f7b39bd.ru6.rcgu.o" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\ru-73038e7f2f7b39bd.ru7.rcgu.o" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\ru-73038e7f2f7b39bd.ru8.rcgu.o" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\ru-73038e7f2f7b39bd.ru9.rcgu.o" "-o" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\ru-73038e7f2f7b39bd.exe" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\ru-73038e7f2f7b39bd.crate.allocator.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-nodefaultlibs" "-L" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps" "-L" "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib" "-L" "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib" "-L" "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib" "-L" "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib" "-L" "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib" "-L" "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib" "-L" "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib" "-L" "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib" "-L" "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib" "-L" "C:\\Users\\Илья\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\libgtk-0b4a468a505c29a6.rlib" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\libgdk-ebd20842bd013b11.rlib" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\libpango-a5cc0f5ec8adc00f.rlib" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\libgdk_pixbuf-252a6e383a6f70bb.rlib" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\libgtk_sys-11c32a4f27c59626.rlib" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\libgdk_sys-9857464aeed9c452.rlib" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\libpango_sys-3f7f8f3dbedb78f0.rlib" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\libgdk_pixbuf_sys-b95a074297ecea1f.rlib" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\libatk_sys-42d0168c076cffbb.rlib" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\libgio-fd4d4503c8627206.rlib" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\libgio_sys-b01857e70d408b08.rlib" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\libcairo-abb6e1489881f7d8.rlib" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\libglib-6b6d3148a88811e1.rlib" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\libgobject_sys-1c36f4639c197ac7.rlib" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\libglib_sys-363f879bf1a50745.rlib" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\liblazy_static-4db6f52f71e2b275.rlib" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\libbitflags-a0c5ccbbea449dc5.rlib" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\libc_vec-66fb41a2be053426.rlib" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\libcairo_sys-9c8ae188b644b7c4.rlib" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\libwinapi-0aed34f6829c55ee.rlib" "D:\\rust\\ru\\target\\debug\\deps\\liblibc-40363f789d24d302.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Илья\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libstd-a0684270ba45e4c4.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Илья\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libpanic_unwind-9959500f08f0e1ba.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Илья\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libunwind-15ac613a7fce0483.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Илья\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\liblibc-8a35d8972d0168d2.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Илья\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\liballoc_system-c3eb086d76a23433.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Илья\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\liballoc-e077f5c433365928.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Илья\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libstd_unicode-fc698978fa4eb61f.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Илья\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcore-732d0577648c664f.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Илья\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcompiler_builtins-8f1b4d5cbd48c220.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-l" "gtk-3" "-l" "gdk-3" "-l" "gdk-3" "-l" "pango-1.0" "-l" "gdk_pixbuf-2.0" "-l" "atk-1.0" "-l" "gio-2.0" "-l" "gobject-2.0" "-l" "glib-2.0" "-l" "gobject-2.0" "-l" "cairo" "-l" "advapi32" "-l" "ws2_32" "-l" "userenv" "-l" "shell32" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "-l" "gcc_eh" "-l" "pthread" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lmingwex" "-lmingw32" "-lgcc" "-lmsvcrt" "-luser32" "-lkernel32" "C:\\Users\\Илья\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rsend.o"
  = note: ld: cannot find -lgtk-3
          ld: cannot find -lgdk-3
          ld: cannot find -lgdk-3
          ld: cannot find -lpango-1.0
          ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
          ld: cannot find -latk-1.0
          ld: cannot find -lgio-2.0
          ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
          ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
          ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
          ld: cannot find -lcairo


error: aborting due to previous error

error: Could not compile `ru`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Как исправить? Я пытался использовать и другой компилятор и версию, а разницы нет везде ошибка есть.

Comment: Что вы уже предприняли, чтобы устранитьь ошибку?

Comment: Переустанавливал сам раст, менял компилятор, менял версию, кто-то писал что надо mingw установить, его ещё устанавливал через msys2.

Comment: Есть подорение, что дело в русских буквах в пути. Попробуйте создать пользователя на латинице и на нем повторить.

Comment: Вы же делали предварительную установку зависимостей из оригинальной документации? http://gtk-rs.org/docs/requirements.html

Comment: Я всё из этого сделал

Comment: Согласен с @AlexZhukovskiy. Но необязательно создавать нового пользователя, можно  перенести rustup в другую папку с помощью переменной среды RUSTUP_HOME. https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs#environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте обновить стабильный компилятор. Похоже, проблема, как я и предполагал, в русском пути. Смотрите [патчноут 1.24.1](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2018/03/01/Rust-1.24.1.html), второй параграф "**Emit UTF-16 files for linker arguments on Windows**".

И на будущее, не используйте в путях не-ascii. От очень многих проблем спасает. Особенно при разработке.